# innerHTML issue when writing value to div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that is a JavaScript slider. When its moved, it outputs the value to an input textarea. I would like to write it to a div; however, I can't seem to get it working using innerhtml.

```
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
var slider=new Array();
slider[1]=new Object();
slider[1].min=0;
slider[1].max=200;
slider[1].val=0;
slider[1].onchange=setBoxValue;
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
function setBoxValue(val, box) {
var b=document.getElementById('output'+box);
val=Math.round(val*1000)/1000;
b.value=val;

// THIS IS WHAT I CANT SEEM TO GET WORKING, DOES THE SYNTAX LOOK OKAY?    
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML='value'; 

}
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
```

Comment: Does the markup actually contain an element with ID `test`?

Comment: If you are using Jquery you can write `$('#test').html('value')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've tagged jQuery, you can just use:

```
$("#test").val("value");
```

Comment: The OP is already using `innerHTML` so what are you referring to?

Comment: It was written as `innerhtml` originally- I'll remove that bit now.

Comment: `html()` is no good for a `textarea` which does not have an `innerHTML` property.

Comment: Fair enough, I just saw the title of the question and assumed it was a `<div>`- have modified above.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the discription, I am assuming that `test` is a [textarea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/textarea). A textarea does not have an innerHTML property. If you want to set the value, use value.

```
document.getElementById('test').value='value';
```

with jQuery you set the value with [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

```
jQuery("#test").val("value");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting innerhtml as the effective integer value from the slider (not the string 'value'):

```
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML= String(val);
```